# Have minor problem, when I'm printing the result

Tags: javascript

this is the code I have problem with :

```js
function strongBrickwall(dimensions, bricks) {
  let rows = dimensions[0];
  let columns = dimensions[1];
  let arr = [];
  let newArr = [];
  let allBricks = bricks.slice();

  if (rows * columns > allBricks.length || rows * columns < allBricks.length) {
    console.log('-1');
  } else if (rows % 2 !== 0 && columns % 2 !== 0) {
    console.log('-1');
  } else if (rows % 2 === 0 && columns % 2 !== 0) {
    console.log('-1');
  } else if (rows % 2 !== 0 && columns % 2 === 0) {
    console.log('-1');
  } else if (rows > 100 || columns > 100) {
    console.log('-1');
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < bricks.length; i += bricks.length / rows) {
      arr.push(bricks.shift());
      arr.push(bricks.pop());
    }
    let slicedBricks = bricks.slice();
    for (let i = 0; i < slicedBricks.length; i += 2) {
      if (newArr[0] == undefined) {
        newArr.unshift(arr.shift());
      }
      for (let j = 0; j < slicedBricks.length; j += 2) {
        newArr.push(bricks.shift());
        if (newArr.length == columns - 1) {
          newArr.push(arr.shift());
          console.log(newArr.join(' '));
          newArr = [];
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
strongBrickwall([6, 6], [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15,
  15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18
]);
```

basically, it gives the result I need but at the bottom it prints a lot of empty spaces and I can't seem to find what's the problem. If I change the values from the first array from [6,6] to for example [2,4] or [4,4] everything works OK(mean that at the bottom are no spaces).

Comment: FYI: `(rows * columns > allBricks.length || rows * columns < allBricks.length)` is the same as `(rows * columns != allBricks.length)`

Comment: Yup, ty for that i'll change it in my code.

Comment: The blank lines are when all the elements of `newArr` are `undefined`. `newArr.unshift(arr.shift());` will do that if `arr` is empty.

Comment: Oooh, I fixed it now with a simple check whether the arr is empty. Thank you so much